# Fast check if custom TLD is resolvable in

Tags: dig

In our mesh network we announce some own top level domains, each community announces its own TLD.

I want to check via bash if the top level domains `.ffhh`, `.ffki` and `.fffl`,...  can be resolved. I created this script using `dig` :

```
# Top Level Domain of your community
echo -n "automatic tld detection."
for tld in ffki fffl ffnord ffhh fmdk dn42 com; do
  echo -n "."
  dig $tld|grep -q NOERROR
  if [ "$?" == "0" ]; then
    COMMUNITY_TLD=$tld
    break
  fi
done
echo " $COMMUNITY_TLD"
```

But this is really slow on some tlds. (For testing, I added the TDS  .dn42 and .com, the last should resolve always.)

Is there a faster way?

Comment: How do people pronounce `.ffki`, especially when they are in a bad mood?

Comment: I'm afraid to inform you this doesn't work on my network, I get an immediate NOERROR for all :).  No answer either; it's not a ISP advertising hijack.  ISP DNS servers are fine.  Router is OpenWrt.  I strongly suspect some "don't spam the root dns with nodots queries" setting in dnsmasq.

Comment: We announce those domains in our mesh network. each community announces its own TLD

Comment: I wanted to point out that if you run this script on a network outside these communities, it's possible you will get the incorrect answer "all of them".  Or rather, given the above code, "the first one in the list".

Comment: no, If i use `| grep NOERROR` this results in 0 if the line "noerror" exists, so it works like it is. I tested it and it works fine. it is just REALLY slow! Is there another command than `dig`, that doesent get stuck so long, if the domain is not resolveable?

Comment: Set the time/tries/retry dig options?

Comment: BTW, how are addresses being issued?  If DHCP, could you perhaps set DHCP options that the client could use to get the information, instead of probing?